# iOS extreme blur effect

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, core-image

I am trying to achieve a blur effect like this:

[image: This is the iOS 7 version of Rdio]

As you can see, the background image is the album art, but it is super blurred. I have tried to use Apples UIImage+ImageEffects category, but it doesn't come close to the amount of blur I need. Does anyone know how to do this, or of any libraries that can achieve this effect?

Comment: It's not only blurred, it's magnified as well.

Comment: That is true. I achieved the magnification effect with UIImage+ImageEffects, but I could never get this level of blur.

Comment: What are you passing in for `blurRadius`?

Comment: I've tried everything from `20` to `1`

Comment: My suggestion is to try to reproduce this first with Photoshop, then see what filters you've used in Photoshop and use them in code. My opinion is that you cannot achieve this only with normal blur.

Answer (score 0):

I've used [LBBlurredImage](https://github.com/lukabernardi/LBBlurredImage) to achieve *ultimate blurriness*:

```
self.backgroundImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bg"]];
self.backgroundImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
[self.backgroundImageView setImageToBlur: [UIImage imageNamed:@"bg"] blurRadius: 50 completionBlock: nil];
[self.view addSubview:self.backgroundImageView];
```

Swift:

```
let backgroundImageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "bg"))
backgroundImageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFill
backgroundImageView.setImageToBlur(UIImage(named: "bg"), blurRadius: 50, completionBlock: nil)
self.view.addSubview(backgroundView)
```